# Calling GetHandleInformation before any call to CloseHandle

Tags: c, windows, winapi, native, window-handles

Fact 1: Due to some client-constraints we are unable to use Exception mechanism.

Fact 2: Closing a handle which was already closed raises an Exception.

Without going through the reasons for the mention facts, will calling `GetHandleInformation()` to detect whether or not the handle is still valid, and only *if it is* calling `CloseHandle()` would be a good way of avoiding such an exception?

Comment: Don't close it in the first place. Fix your code properly.

Comment: After closing a handle I usually set the handle to NULL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must not access a closed handle in any way, as it may refer to a different handle due to handle recycling.

> handle recycling means that any invalid handle can suddenly become valid again (but refer to an unrelated object).

[Raymond Chen - The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/09/26/10353221.aspx).